# WCF Service Deserialization failed with DataTable from .NET 4.5 Server to .NET 3.0 Client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

When WCF Service returns a DataTable nested in as DataSet cell value (not as Table), deserialization on client side fails.

I'm taking a look to the traffic with Fidder and found that following part:

```
msdata:InstanceType="System.Data.DataTable, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
```

This may make deserialization failed, because .NET 3.0 doesn't know this type.

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem without update client .net version?

Thanks :)

#### Error Message

Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type

#### Stack Trace

```
  Server stack trace: 
     At System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
     At System.Data.Common.ObjectStorage.ConvertXmlToObject(XmlReader xmlReader, XmlRootAttribute xmlAttrib)
     At System.Data.XmlDataLoader.LoadColumn(DataColumn column, Object[] foundColumns)
     At System.Data.XmlDataLoader.LoadTable(DataTable table, Boolean isNested)
     At System.Data.XmlDataLoader.LoadData(XmlReader reader)
     At System.Data.DataSet.ReadXmlDiffgram(XmlReader reader)
     At System.Data.DataSet.ReadXml(XmlReader reader, XmlReadMode mode, Boolean denyResolving)
     At System.Data.DataSet.ReadXmlSerializable(XmlReader reader)
     At System.Data.DataSet.System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
     At System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadIXmlSerializable(XmlSerializableReader xmlSerializableReader, XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlDataContract xmlDataContract, Boolean isMemberType)
     At System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadIXmlSerializable(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlDataContract xmlDataContract, Boolean isMemberType)
     At System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
     At System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
     At System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, DataContract& dataContract)
     At System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns)
     At System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
     At System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
     At System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
     At System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
     At System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameter(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
     At System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameters(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
     At System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
     At System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
     At System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
     At System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
     At System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
     At System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
     At System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
     At System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
     At System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

  Exception rethrown at [0]: 
     At System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
     At System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
```

Comment: In my case, all tables and dataset have name.

Comment: Take a look at [THIS](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registering `AssemblyResolve` fixed this problem.

I select a loading assembly with same name(without version) of target assembly, and this works perfectly.